# If statement Validation

Tags: java, validation

trying to write a simple Java program that accepts a string and validates against two criteria.

If the word is shorter than 4 letter it asks the user to re enter a word till it is four letters..

Once that criteria is true it evaluates it against the letters. If the first letter of the four letter word is a D then it prints a silly message "The D was found" if not "No D found"

So far what i have working is validation for the four letters. It checks that it is four letters and if its not it keeps asking till it gets a four letter word.

After that when i enter the four letter word i cant get it to validate on the next if which checks if it is greater than 4 letters and then checks if it starts with a D or not.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class POD1

{

private static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

```
private static String word;
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter a 4 Letter word");
    word = scan.next();

    if(word.length() <4) 
    {    
        System.out.println("Word is to short ");
        System.out.println("Plese re-enter");
        word = scan.next();
    }

    if(word.length() > 4)
    {
        if(word.charAt(1) == 'd')      
        {
            System.out.println("Big d"); 
        } else

        if( word.charAt(1) !='d')
        {
            System.out.println("No big d");
        }
    } 
}
```

}

UPDATE

The code now does go past 4 letter words but even if the word starts with a d it prints out no big d even though it starts with a d

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: You might want to consider using loops. What if, for example, the user enters a short word the second time? Also, here is a very god place where you could use the `else` keyword (not `else if (...)`, just plain `else`).

Comment: Oh and there's a very big difference between `'d'` and `'D'`.

Comment: The other thing: the first index is 0 **not** 1. Arrays, Lists, strings are zero-index based in Java; as in most other programming languages, too.

Answer (score 4):

You should be having the following to include 4 lettered words as well

```
if(word.length() >= 4)
```

You are scanning and taking the input until word.length() <4. So the loop breaks when the length is 4.

So, it doesn't enter the next if statement.

A better implementation would be to use the **`else`** clause

```
    if(word.length() <4) {  

        System.out.println("Word is to short ");
        System.out.println("Plese re-enter");
        word = scan.next();

    } else {

        if(word.charAt(0) == 'D')      
        {
            System.out.println("Big D"); 
        } else

        if( word.charAt(0) !='D')
        {
            System.out.println("No big D");
        }
    } 
}
```

Also, you should be checking for **'D'** and not **'d'**, if you are looking for *"Big D"*.

Also, the index of the first character in a String is 0. So, you should be using **`word.charAt(0) == 'D'`**, and not index 1 as you are using in your code right now. Index 1 will return the second character.

Comment: Feel free to upvote and accept the answer if the solution worked for you. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

You check wether the word is shorter than 4 letters AND wether the word is longer than 4 letters.

There is absolutely nothing in your code that includes 4 letter words.

```
if(word.length() >= 4)
```

should be used.

Comment: Thank You ... Worked like a charm

Comment: Happy to help. You should accept the other answer  (Swayams) though, it expands on a few other points that I didn't really look at and is imho overall better :)